# Strange IndexOutOfBoundsException when loading a long String into a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am not doing any sort of crazy String manipulation. This is a very, very strange error to me.

This is the stack trace I've seen...once and only once...ever:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:158)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:312)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:44)
    at java.util.Formatter.outputCharSequence(Formatter.java:1115)
    at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1105)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1063)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1032)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2104)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2078)
    at com.my.app.package.myWebViewClient.onPageFinished(Unknown Source)
    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:270)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3998)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In myWebViewClient's onPageFinished, I tell the myWebView to load this script:

```
String A_VERY_LONG_SCRIPT = "a very long script" +
                                 "that I format" +  \\ some comment!
                                 "in the source code!!" +
                            "some other things" +
                                 "to make this script look really long";
String jsString = String.format("javascript:try{%s}catch(e){}", A_VERY_LONG_SCRIPT);
myWebView.loadUrl(jsString);
```

Does the String.format call have a length limit or something? And if that's the reason, how come I can't reproduce this 100% of the time or even 80% of the time?

I cannot reproduce this exception. I've only ever seen it once even though I'm loading this script many times in every test. I haven't changed the code since seeing the exception. I've tested against different OS versions. I just can't seem to trigger the exception again, but I'm wondering why the heck I saw it in the first place.

So, what is causing this IndexOutOfBoundsException???

I'm developing for Android 3.0+.

Comment: The code that crashes involves `String.format` and is in `myWebViewClient.onPageFinished`. Please show the relevant code. You might be passing invalid parameters to `String.format`.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I forgot to add the String.format call!